# Any way to set up AWS Cloudfront to point to static IP address (WP hosted on GoDaddy)?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

So I have a Wordpress site hosted on Godaddy, but the DNS is on Route53, and I'd like it to be accessed only over https.

So I set up an SSL cert using ACM and a Cloudfront distribution which uses that cert, but all I have from GoDaddy is an IP address Cloudfront doesn't allow me to set the origin to an IP.

Any way to get this done?

Comment: You will want to configure your domain name to point to a `CNAME` rather than an `A` record. This will allow you to enter the DNS name of your CloudFront distribution. See: https://au.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236

Answer (score 14):

Make up a new hostname.  If your domain is example.com, then call it `origin.example.com`.  The name doesn't actually matter as long as it's currently unused and is in a domain you control.

Create an A record in Route 53 pointing `origin.example.com` to the IP address of your server.

Then, in CloudFront, set the Origin Domain Name to `origin.example.com`.  Set the Origin Protocol Policy to "HTTP Only."  In the Cache Behavior settings, whitelist the `Host` header for forwarding to the origin.

CloudFront will use that name to find the server's IP address via Route 53.

Comment: That's a great solution! Helped me heaps. Thanks!